# Obtain a formula for the projection $P_D$ and prove it using angle characterization

Tags: optimization, hilbert-spaces

Consider the Hilbert product space $X\times X$. In this space, define the closed convex “diagonal” set by
$$D := \{(x,x) | x \in X\}.$$

Obtain a formula for the projection $P_D$ and prove it.

I am stuck on this problem. I know that I need to start by using the definition of a projection but I am not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to find what is $D^{\perp}$. If $(x,y)$ is in $D^{\perp}$, then we have $<(x,y),(u,u)>=<x,u>+<y,u>=<x+y,u>=0$ for all $u\in X$. You can finish easily. Then, if $(x,y)\in X\times X$, you want to write $(x,y)=(u,u)+w$, with $w\in D^{\perp}$. Use what you have find above to explicitely find $u$. Then $P_D((x,y))=(u,u)$.

Comment: Thank you, I am still unsure who to go about finding D⊥. Do I need to use the distance function?

Comment: The fact that if $(x,y)$ is in $D^{\perp}$ imply that $<x+y,u>=0$ for all $u\in X$. You can take $u=x+y$, and this show that $y=-x$. So $D^{\perp}$ is the set of $(v,-v)$ for $v\in X$. So my $w$ above can be written $(v,-v)$. You have $x=u+v$, $y=u-v$. Find $u$ (and $v$), and you are done.

Comment: Okay, so then to solve for u to get PD((x,y))=(u,u), I just manipulate those x and y values and solve for u, correct?

Comment: Yes, you have to find $u,v$ such that x=u+v$, y=u-v$, and then the projection of $(x,y)$ on $D$ is $(u,u)$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, as you can tell, I am struggling with this problem haha so I really appreciate it